# Box appears before option is selected?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select, dropdownbox

I have a drop down list that is supposed to open a new list when a certain option is selected, for whatever reason one of the hidden boxes appears when I reload the page but goes away when I select an option that isn't connected to that box.

```js
function CheckDep(val)
{
    var element=document.getElementById('line')
    if(val=='others')
        element.style.display='block'
    else
        element.style.display='none';
    var element=document.getElementById('manufact')
    if (val=='machine')
        element.style.display='block'
    else
        element.style.display='none';
}
```

```html
<body>
    <label for="color">Department:</label>
    <select name="color" onchange='CheckDep(this.value);'>
        <option></option>
        <option value="ware">Warehouse</option>
        <option value="machine">Manufacturing</option>
        <option value="others">Packaging</option>
    </select>

    <select type="text" name="color" id="manufact" style='display:none;'>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="hi">hi</option>
    </select>

    <select type="text" name="color" id="line" style='display:none;'>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You have a typo in inline styles of `id="manufact"`. Works expected after correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The style in the following select element is not correct:

```
<select type="text" name="color" id="manufact" style='display;none;'>
```

It has to be as follow:

```
<select type="text" name="color" id="manufact" style='display:none;'>
```

Also there is mistake in the following select element:

```
<select type="text" name="color" id="line" style='display:none;'/>
```

It has to be as follow:

```
<select type="text" name="color" id="line" style='display:none;'>
```

Also you need to use closing tag for that select element `</select>`